# Read system Call

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am trying my hands with unix socket programming in C. But while reading I am getting Err No as 4. I am unable to find out the description of this error code. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you would start with looking at ultimate source of Unix error code names (`/usr/include/errno.h`) you'll arrive at the file which contains your error code as

```
#define EINTR            4      /* Interrupted system call */
```

(Which is this file is left for you to find out, as an exercise ;))

Answer (score 2):

The `errno` values can be different for different systems (even different Unix-like systems), so the symbolic constants should be used in code.

The `perror` function will print out (to *stderr* ) a descriptive string of the last `errno` value along with a string you provide.

```
man 3 perror
```

The `strerror` function simply returns a `const char *` to the string that `perror` prints.

If 4 is `EINTR` on your system then you received a signal during your call to read.  There are ways to keep this from interrupting your system calls, but often you just need to:

```
while (1) {
   ssize_t x = read(file, buf, len);
   if (x < 0) {
       if (errno == EINTR) {
           errno = 0;
           continue;
       } else {
          // it's a real error
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `EINTR`, it probably means you've installed a signal handler improperly. Good unices will default to restartable system calls when you simply call `signal`, but for safety, you should either use the `bsd_signal` function if it's available, or call `sigaction` with the restartable flag to avoid the headaches of `EINTR`.